# Unknown encoding error on running rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have been writing a Rails app and only now started bringing it under 
test coverage. I have written a basic test and when I execute the 
'rake' command at the command prompt, I get the following errors:

```
E:\testapp>rake 
(in E:/testapp) 
E:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe: unknown encoding name - \Ruby192\lib 
(RuntimeError) 
E:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe: unknown encoding name - \Ruby192\lib 
(RuntimeError) 
E:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe: unknown encoding name - \Ruby192\lib 
(RuntimeError) 
Errors running test:units, test:functionals, test:integration!
```

When I run rake test:units, I get

```
E:\testapp>rake test:units 
(in E:/testapp) 
E:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe: unknown encoding name - \Ruby192\lib 
(RuntimeError) 
rake aborted! 
Command failed with status (1): [E:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe -I"lib;test" 
"E:/R...] 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:993:in `block in sh' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1008:in `call' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1008:in `sh' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1092:in `sh' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1027:in `ruby' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1092:in `ruby' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:26:in `block (2 levels) in define' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1110:in `verbose' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:11:in `block in define' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block ininvoke_with_call_chain' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) intop_level' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in`standard_exception_handling' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level' 
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run' 
E:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

I have tried searching on the Net to no success.. I initially assumed 
something was wrong with my test code, but I get the same errors with 
a new rails app!!

I am using Rails 3.0.5 on Ruby 1.9.2p180 on Windows Vista. On a friend's suggestion, I 
installed RubyInstaller and used DevKit, but I still get the same 
error.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the path it seems you are pointing to ruby 1.9.1

E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/**1.9.1**/rake.rb

I'm not familiar with Windows but something must still be pointing at the old Ruby version

Comment: I did notice that.. but I deleted the entire folder after uninsttallation and then reinstalled Ruby. I still got this... so I guess it's part of Ruby Installer.